# WAMP server and live server act differently - Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php, session, wamp

I have a project which calls lots of AJAX PHP pages which have `session_start();` called. It works fine in a WAMP server (localhost) but when I host this project on a live server it shows:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent message

This warning error is removable when I remove `session_start();` in AJAX PHP pages
and program works fine in live server but not in WAMP server (localhost) program fails.

Is there something that I have to configure in the WAMP server which works exactly like live server?

Comment: Sounds like the live server may have `session.auto_start` set. Look at a `phpinfo()` output on the live server to check that

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you need to have `session_start();` only in the first PHP file you're loading - consequent loads of PHP pages will use the same session. 
`session_start();` creates a new session which will be used wherever `$_SESSION` variables are accessed, even in other PHP pages in the same context.

Please refer the [documentation for `session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)